# Dynamic making Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a working solution with dynamic regex in Javascript.

this solution works for me: (but is not dynamic)

```
new RegExp(\bal\i);
```

but this solution is not working:

```
var value = 'bal';
new RegExp('\'+value+'\i');
```

Could anyone help me how to adjust it to make it work? Thank you

Comment: Pass a string to RegExp constructor, see what the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description)  say ...

Comment: for example balicekt123@gmail.com but there can be what ever first name or last name

Comment: Did you mean `/bal/i` as a working regex?

Comment: yes exactly /bal/i is working for me but I need to change word "bal" for something what will be dynamic what will come to the function like a parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass the string (value) in the RegExp constructor, along with the ignoreCase flag as:

```
 var value = 'bal';
 var b = new RegExp(value, 'i')
 b.test('BAL')
```

it returns true.

Comment: Of course a constructor should be used. People post such questions dozens times a day.